# For loop in cpp for stringstream operations

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

while using stringstream, I came across a piece for Parsing a comma-delimited std::string as below; I find `for` loop operation unique and new contrary to conventional operation as `for(statement 1;statement 2;statement 3)`, I would like to understand this for loop `for (int i; ss >> i;)` used in below code, please let me know about these different use, thanks a lot.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
    std::vector<int> vect;

    std::stringstream ss(str);

    for (int i; ss >> i;) {
        vect.push_back(i);    
        if (ss.peek() == ',')
            ss.ignore();
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vect[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It declares an int to use for extraction and then runs until `ss >> i` fails, because the stream is empty or non int data in the stream.

Comment: It is the same concept. `int i` declares a new variable called `i` which is an integer. The condition, `ss >> i` is true while the read is good, and also sets the value of `i` . There is no need for an "update" portion of the for loop, since that is handled by the condition.

Comment: I would recommend reading some more about C++ `for` loops.  For instance [cppreference.com have a nice [explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for#explanation).

Comment: It has no explicit increment step, that’s all. That’s why the third statement is empty. (E.g. an infinite loop would be `for (;;) { ... }`.) The “increment” (a read from a stream) is happening implicitly as a side effect of the condition evaluation. The condition evaluation takes the result of `std::stringstream& std::stringstream::operator >>(int&)` on `ss`, which usually returns a reference to itself (so that `ss >> i >> j;` can also work) and then `std::stringstream::operator bool()` is called on the result (i.e. on `ss`), which implements something like `!(ss.fail() || ss.bad())`.